# f:ajax not rendering table on included page

Tags: ajax, jsf-2

I have a table of users, click on a username and a table of the users data is displayed under the table of users. This works only issue is the `h:commandLink` submits the form and the entire page reloads, the proper data is shown but the page reloads.

The table of user data is on another page which is included from a `ui:include`. The page has a rendered condition based on the selected users dataset. Here is the button in question:

```
h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Username " />
        </f:facet>
        <h:commandLink value="#{user.username}" immediate="true">
            <f:param name="username" value="#{user.username}" />
            <f:ajax
                render="-welcomePageForm-grootPageSubView-adminUserPageSubview-testSubviewUserPage-entriesTable"></f:ajax>
        </h:commandLink>
    </h:column>
```

As you can see I am using the absolute path to the table on the included page, this however does not work and I do not know why.

Quick note, this `h:column` is obviously in a datatable, all of this is in a `f:subview` not that it should matter. All surrounding elements have an id, there are no nested forms. And I am out of ideas as to why this does not work.

If you could help I greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Nested naming container are referenced using the `:` prefix to the container ids, so `render=" "` should read something like:

```
render=":welcomePageForm:grootPageSubView:adminUserPageSubview:testSubviewUserPage:entriesTable"
```

Comment: Normally it would be but in web.xml I changed the : character to the - character. Until I changed the character jQuery would throw syntax errors